# PayPal SDK for android, Log in and receive token for auto payments

Tags: android, sdk, paypal

I'm developing some sort of e-Wallet and would like to integrate PayPal into it.
One of the features I need is the ability to Log in to PayPal once and link it to a users account, allowing him to make small transactions (No more than 10$-15$ a day) without further PayPal logins.

For example logging in to PayPal and receiving a unique token I can save to a users account the way credit card companies work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK does not have support for this feature yet although we are working on making it available really soon. In the meantime, you may want to explore one of the two options:
1) express checkout with reference transaction: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/
2) Adaptive Payments Preapproval API: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

Both have a mobile optimized login page which you can open in a WebView. For option #2 the redirect is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?expType=redirect&preapprovalKey=.

Hope this helps.